# C# & XAML - TextBox binding not updating content

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a TextBox in a Stackpanel, as in the code below

```
<StackPanel x:Name="EtenStack" Visibility="{Binding Path=Sort, ConverterParameter=Eten, Converter={StaticResource convertEten}}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Label Content="Bereidingstijd"/>
                <TextBox Height="23" Width="150" Text="{Binding Path=Time, TargetNullValue='', Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </StackPanel>
```

When the Visibility is set to Visible in my converter, my textbox doesn't update it's Text property, even though the Property gets it's correct value (tested by showing a MessageBox with the Property).

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you call the notifypropertychanged event for visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Time` property will need to be either a Dependency Property with the right binding or on a class that Implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface, for the `Time` property, in order for the update to occur "Automatically."

Comment: Time was a Dependency Property, I changed it to a regular property and implemented INotifyPropertyChanged and hurrah, it worked!
Thanks @Jodrell